# why JSP pages not showing when using multiple view resolver in Spring boot?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I have added multiple view resolver for PDF, Excel and InternalResourceViewResolver for JSP files. PDF and Excel resolver works fine but when I call /test that is calling my test (test.jsp) I see a blank page. But when I remove other resolvers or disable my webconfig then test.jsp (/test) loads fine.

Following is the error I see when calling /test (binded to test controller and test.jsp):

```
2018-08-11 23:43:06.191 ERROR 12136 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/test] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Also, following is my webconfig responsible for adding multiple resolvers (pdf, excel and jsp pages):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .favorPathExtension(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    /*
     * Configure ContentNegotiatingViewResolver
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);

        // Define all possible view resolvers
        List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<>();

        resolvers.add(internalResourceViewResolver());
        resolvers.add(pdfViewResolver());
        resolvers.add(excelViewResolver());

        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    /*
     * Configure View resolver to provide XLS output using Apache POI library to
     * generate XLS output for an object content
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver excelViewResolver() {
        return new ExcelViewResolver();
    }

    /*
     * Configure View resolver to provide Pdf output using iText library to
     * generate pdf output for an object content
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver pdfViewResolver() {
        return new PdfViewResolver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you added controller class?

Comment: yes. Actually i found the problem. it was strangely only a missing slash. fixed by just adding that at end of the path that jsp files resides: resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");